# Text ocupies all with of the device without any margin bottom

Tags: html, css

I need to achieve:

[image]

the text "contact us" occupies the entire width in one line on any device and does not have any bottom margin, always at the bottom of the device without any space. However when I resize the window it creates a margin, I don't put fixed as it is only on one section of the page. How can I do that?

I have this code:

```css
.slide {
  height: 100vh;
  background: black;

}

.slide:after {
  content: "Contact us";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 16vw;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  max-height: 334px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide section1">
</div>
```

Finally the solution was the next:

```
<div class="slide">
  <div class="other-content"></div>
  <div class="contact">Contact us</div>
</div>

.slide {
  height: 100vh;
  background: black;    
}

.contact {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16.5vw;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 0.7;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

https://codepen.io/cabita/pen/bGeBJQW

Comment: I can't see the margin at bottom of the text when resizing the window

Comment: I have updated the image, so you can see what is the margin or space between the text and border of the window.

Comment: You mean the tiny little sliver of white on the right edge of the image?

Comment: I need the text occupies 100% of the screen, and I can not see the space remarked in pink on the above image in any device.

Comment: It might be helpful to create a jsfiddle like this one.  Not just for you, but for other developers to jump to help you in a hurry.  http://jsfiddle.net/fiddler_on_the_web/2n9be997/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you. You can play with `line-height` to adjust the space at the bottom of the text.

```css
.slide {
  height:100vh;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  width: 100vw;
  background: #000;
  max-height: 334px;
  font-size: 15vw;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  line-height: 0.7;
}

.slide:after {
  content: "Contact us";
}
```

```html
<div class="slide section1">
</div>
```

Comment: I found the way, the solution was a mix between your answer and  jsfiddle.net/fiddler_on_the_web/2n9be997.   I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: It was useful line-height and display flex-end.

Comment: Glad to know that it helped you fix the issue ✌️